# Can no longer boot from HD after installation of latest 12.04 update

Tags: 12.04, grub-efi

The following message was seen at upgrade process (during installation of grub-efi-amd64): "Fatal: Couldnt open either sysfs or procfs directories for acessing EFI variables. Try 'modprobe efivars' as root".

Obviously there is no longer a bootable grub on my HD.

Before that upgrade everything went fine on my Thinkpad Edge 13" E325 with 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

An inability to access efisys or procfs should not have damaged whatever was there before, so unless this failure caused some sort of suicidal self-destruct to occur, the system should still boot. OTOH, putting on my cynical hat, it wouldn't surprise me too much if such a failure *would* result in the package uninstalling critical files....

Anyhow, if your system really is unbootable, my recommendation is to manually install a boot loader using an emergency boot disc. You should be able to get Ubuntu's grub-efi-amd64 package to install via either of at least two methods (using the --root option to dpkg in an emergency boot or by chrooting into your regular system and using dpkg or apt-get in a normal way). Alternatively, you can install any EFI boot loader that you care to try via non-package-manager methods. Typically, you just need to copy a handful of files to the EFI System Partition (ESP) and set up a configuration file or two. There are four major options (in order of reliability, they are the kernel's EFI stub loader in 3.3.0 and later kernels, ELILO, GRUB Legacy, and GRUB 2). See [my Web page on the topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for more information about all of these; there's far too much to say about them to fit into a reply here.